# Why am I getting "_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle" error while using the PythonVirtualenvOperator in airflow in GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, virtualenv, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to use the PythonVirtualenvOperator from airflow to create an virtual environment for a specific task to run.
I'm just replicating the example given in the airflow documentation first,

My Main py and Dag py are two different files,

**Main.py file looks like below** :

```
from airflow.decorators import task

@task.virtualenv(
    task_id="virtualenv_python", requirements=["colorama==0.4.0"], system_site_packages=True
)

def Main_func():
    from time import sleep
    from colorama import Back, Fore, Style

    print(Fore.RED + "some red text")
    print(Back.GREEN + "and with a green background")
    print(Style.DIM + "and in dim text")
    print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    for _ in range(4):
        print(Style.DIM + "Please wait...", flush=True)
        sleep(1)
    print("Finished")
```

**task_dag.py looks like below** :

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from Main import Main_func

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'max_active_runs': 1,
}

Main_Mod_dag = DAG(
    'Main_Mod_Run',
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Main Module Run',
    schedule_interval='48 11 * * 3',
    start_date=datetime(2022, 12, 11),
    tags=['Main_Mod'],
)

Main_Mod_Func = PythonOperator(task_id='Main_Mod', python_callable=Main_func, dag=Main_Mod_dag)

Main_Mod_Func
```

**Expected Results:**
successful schedule -> Run -> all the print statements in the log

**Error : **

`[2023-05-10, 10:47:13 UTC] {python.py:177} INFO - Done. Returned value was: {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='virtualenv_python', dag_id='adhoc_airflow', key='return_value') }} [2023-05-10, 10:47:13 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1853} ERROR - Task failed with exception Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 72, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 2381, in xcom_push XCom.set( File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 72, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 206, in set value = cls.serialize_value( File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 595, in serialize_value return pickle.dumps(value) _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function Main_func at 0x7fe5c18dba60>: it's not the same object as Main.Main_func`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call decorated functions in python_callable.

See some examples how you can do

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/example_dags/example_python_operator.py

In your code:

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag
from datetime import datetime
from Main import Main_func

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "max_active_runs": 1,
}


@dag(
    dag_id="Main_Mod_Run",
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    description="Main Module Run",
    schedule_interval="48 11 * * 3",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 12, 11),
    tags=["Main_Mod"],
)
def my_dag():
    Main_Mod_Func = Main_func()

my_dag = my_dag()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, There wasn't any issue with the Dag as it works fine when I ignore the virtualenv concept and just install the packages in the pypi packages list in gcp.
Whene you say I cannot call decorated functions inpython callable, does that mean that I would need to use @task decorator in the dag itself? because as the airflow documentation suggests, I need to use the task decorator to create a virtual environment to run the task.
The aim for me is to create a virtualenv for the tasks to be run on without depending on the airfflow base environment, if that makes sense?

Comment: @Ruscinic
PythonVirtualenvOperator - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html
this is what i'm trying to acheive.

Comment: The dag example in the git link is exactly what I'm trying to do, the only diff is I'm using a separate file for the dag. Does it mean that the "@task.virtualenv"  will only work if the callable function is defined with the dag in a single file?
Could you please help?

Comment: sry for late.. I see you achieve the funcionality...  and you can use a separate file.. I tried here now and works! See my import
`
@dag(
    dag_id="000_dbs_test_dag",
    description="DAG for Ops Support",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 7, 23, 11, 45),
    tags=["test"],
)
def my_dag():
    # t0 = PythonOperator(
    #     task_id="Main_func",
    #     python_callable=Main_func,
    # )
    from Main import Main_func
    t0 = Main_func()


my_dag = my_dag()`

Comment: Hi, that's alright, what you've mentioned works only for the dag decorator and not for the task decorator. Try using the task decorator to create an virtual environment - both in two separate file concept and single dag file concept, you'll actually see what I'm saying.
you can use the example I've put in the solution.
@Ruscinc thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried out different scenarios to make this work and my inference is that, the virtualenv works with the task decorator only when it is put inside the same python file with the dag and the python callable function, the task decorator with the virtualenv needs to be immediately above the function definition else the dag throws error while getting built in gcp.
The link from git that @Ruscinic posted helped on this -

I wanted to split the Dag file and the python callable file to make it more organised but it doesn't help if I want to use the virtualenv concept for the tasks.

Below is what I've tried and it works and hope it helps -

```
from airflow.decorators import task

from airflow import DAG

from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "max_active_runs": 1,
}


with DAG(
    dag_id="Main_Mod_Run",
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    description="Main Module Run",
    schedule_interval="6 17 * * 3",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 12, 11),
    tags=["Main_Mod"],
) as dag:
    @task.virtualenv(task_id="virtualenv_python", requirements=["colorama==0.4.0"], system_site_packages=False)
    def callable_virtualenv():
        """
        Example function that will be performed in a virtual environment.
        Importing at the module level ensures that it will not attempt to import the
        library before it is installed.
        """
        from time import sleep
        from colorama import Back, Fore, Style

        print(Fore.RED + "some red text")
        print(Back.GREEN + "and with a green background")
        print(Style.DIM + "and in dim text")
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
        for _ in range(4):
            print(Style.DIM + "Please wait...", flush=True)
            sleep(1)
        print("Finished")


    virtualenv_task = callable_virtualenv()

    virtualenv_task
```

**expected results : **

```
[2023-05-10, 16:11:40 UTC] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - Successfully built autograd-gamma mplcursors future
[2023-05-10, 16:11:41 UTC] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - Installing collected packages: pytz, zipp, tzdata, six, pyparsing, pillow, packaging, numpy, kiwisolver, future, fonttools, docutils, cycler, colorama, scipy, python-dateutil, importlib-resources, contourpy, autograd, pandas, matplotlib, autograd-gamma, mplcursors, reliability
[2023-05-10, 16:11:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - Successfully installed autograd-1.5 autograd-gamma-0.5.0 colorama-0.4.0 contourpy-1.0.7 cycler-0.11.0 docutils-0.17.1 fonttools-4.39.4 future-0.18.3 importlib-resources-5.12.0 kiwisolver-1.4.4 matplotlib-3.7.1 mplcursors-0.5.2 numpy-1.24.3 packaging-23.1 pandas-2.0.1 pillow-9.5.0 pyparsing-3.0.9 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2023.3 reliability-0.8.8 scipy-1.10.1 six-1.16.0 tzdata-2023.3 zipp-3.15.0
[2023-05-10, 16:11:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:179} INFO - Executing cmd: /tmp/venvbzgn1kgr/bin/python /tmp/venvbzgn1kgr/script.py /tmp/venvbzgn1kgr/script.in /tmp/venvbzgn1kgr/script.out /tmp/venvbzgn1kgr/string_args.txt
[2023-05-10, 16:11:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:183} INFO - Output:
[2023-05-10, 16:11:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - [31msome red text
[2023-05-10, 16:11:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - [42mand with a green background
[2023-05-10, 16:11:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - [2mand in dim text
[2023-05-10, 16:11:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - [0m
[2023-05-10, 16:11:59 UTC] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - [2mPlease wait...
[2023-05-10, 16:12:00 UTC] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - [2mPlease wait...
[2023-05-10, 16:12:01 UTC] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - [2mPlease wait...
[2023-05-10, 16:12:02 UTC] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - [2mPlease wait...
[2023-05-10, 16:12:04 UTC] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - Finished
[2023-05-10, 16:12:04 UTC] {python.py:177} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
[2023-05-10, 16:12:04 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1402} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=Main_Mod_Run, task_id=virtualenv_python, execution_date=20230510T161120, start_date=20230510T161122, end_date=20230510T161204
[2023-05-10, 16:12:04 UTC] {local_task_job.py:159} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2023-05-10, 16:12:04 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2626} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```